# Why does not Style.BasedOn work for the style of a child control if parent style was defined in Style.Resources of a parent?

Tags: wpf

I have the style:

```
<Style TargetType="Panel" x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type styles:CommonStyles}, ResourceId=ButtonsPanelStyle}">

        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E0E0E0"/>
        <Setter Property="StackPanel.Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
        <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DesiredSize.Width}"/>

    </Style>
```

And its usage:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                   Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static styles:CommonStyles.ButtonsPanelStyleKey}}">
            <Button  Content="Add" Command="{Binding Add}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="AddButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" TabIndex="2" >
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type Button}}" TargetType="Button">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ActionType}" Value="Edit">
                                <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </DockPanel>
```

The style applied to button does not respect margin set in the style defined inside style's resources. Why?

Comment: Try to use DynamicResource in BasedOn

Comment: @Nikolay BasedOn is not a DependencyProperty. DR can be set only for DPs.